# How would you create an automatic nickname system with an increasing number in the nickname with every new member?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I'm making a Discord server with a bot and I want to automate the process of naming every new member a nickname with a numerical value which is increased with every member which joins. I'll give a small example:

*example1 joins server*
(nicknamed member1)
*example2 joins server*
(nicknamed member2)
etc

Comment: how user is joining server?? rest api or sockets ??

Comment: can you provide the code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches other than using a random function is to increment the nickname number by fetching the last added nickname of the user too database.

```js
let userName = 'example1',//Input userName
 nickName = 'member_' + NextIncrementNumber();

function NextIncrementNumber(){
 let lastAddedUser = 'member_42',//Fetch the last added nickname to database
        returnNumber = 0; //Setting the base case for first user

 if(lastAddedUser != ""){
  returnNumber = parseInt(lastAddedUser.split('_')[1]) + 1;
 }
    return returnNumber
}

console.log(nickName);
```